# How to mark PostgresOperator DAG as failed on condition?

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG running daily at a specific hour. It is a PG operator and fetches a table. like the following:

```
select count(*) from my_table where date_insert='{{ds}}'
```

Now what I need is to mark this task as failed if this count is zero. So I'm guessing I need to return data from DAG to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use case of [SQLCheckOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5a5d50d1e347dfc8d8ee99370c41de3106dea558/airflow/operators/sql.py#L90) which is compatible with PostgreSQL:

```
from airflow.operators.sql import SQLCheckOperator
SQLCheckOperator(
    conn_id='your_conn',
    sql="""select count(*) from my_table where date_insert='{{ds}}'""",
    
)
```

The operator will raise `AirflowException` if `count==0`.